# Powershell - removing rows which contain X number of specified characters

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to write a PowerShell, which looks at the most recent 10 files in a folder. I then want to look in each of these files and remove rows where there are more than 7 or 8 commas based on the file name

At the moment my script is creating empty files?

I have never experienced Powershell before, so I am very much new to it.

```
$Directory = "C:\Users\sys\time\realter"
$RecentFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 10
$regex = ',';

foreach ($file in $RecentFiles) {
    if ($file.name.StartsWith("DL")) {
        Content $file | Where{$regex.matches($_).count -gt 7} | Out-File C:\Users\sys\time\realter\NewFiles\$file.name
    } else {
        Content $file | Where{$regex.matches($_).count -gt 8} | Out-File C:\Users\sys\time\realter\NewFiles\$file.name
    }
}
```

Below is a sample of the data, the 3rd line is badly formatted and contains 8 commas, so needs to be removed.

```
15607085,google,690,DEN,9,Mouse,developer,FT
15607186,yahoo,e9e,DEN,9,Mouse,developer,PT
15607196,outlook,34d,DEN,9,Mouse,de,veloper,FT
15607252,google,b90,DEN,9,Mouse,developer,FT
```

Should become

```
15607085,google,690,DEN,9,Mouse,developer,FT
15607186,yahoo,e9e,DEN,9,Mouse,developer,PT

15607252,google,b90,DEN,9,Mouse,developer,FT
```

I need for the original file to be updated or replaced, I have been working in a separate folder for testing

Comment: Can you show some source file lines and the expected output. I think I get what you are trying to do here but some of the explanation leave a margin of guessing. Input and expected output would be very helpful here.

Comment: I have added an example to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, instead of counting the occurrences of a character I split by that character and count. This produces the desired output.

```
foreach ($file in $RecentFiles) {
    if ($file.name.StartsWith("DL")) {
        Get-Content $file.pspath | Where{$_.Split(",").GetUpperBound(0) -lt 7} | Out-File "$NewDir $file"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that script is pretty well written, if you've just recently started scripting with Power Shell. As far as I can tell you don't really have a line of code, which tells the programm what to output. You only count it and get the check into a new file. perhaps try it with an if statement instead. Then you can tell it what exactly it needs to paste into the new file instead of pipes, which just take what you get.

Hope that helped you but if you got any Questions on how to exactly do it you can write me back.

- CERESIA

Comment: I honestly can't tell how this answers the question